# Running readLine() function of BufferedReader class returns nothing

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline

I am using Mac OS on which I wrote the following java code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

class random9
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/xyz/Desktop/xyz.txt"));  
        br.readLine();
    }
}
```

When I run this file I don't get an output although the program runs successfully without any errror.

(P.S : This is the first question I have asked on stack overflow so I apologize if my question is not phrased correctly.)

Comment: Try to print what you read, e.g `System.out.println(br.readLine())`

Comment: Hi and welcome! try to add a print to your *br_readLine()* to see if it's printing something :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Leviand

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a line from you file via the `BufferedReader` but you did not use it, so nothing happen

You need to store and make something with it like print it

```
String firstLine = br.readLine();
System.out.println("First line is" + firstLine);
//or simply
System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

To read a file with multiple lines you may read a new line nonstop until it’s null :

```
String line;
while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
    System.out.println(line); // or something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time @azro . Works like a charm !!

Comment: @mrigankshankar if this answer meets your requirements, don’t hesitate to côté up/accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
        System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

or if file contains more then 1 row then you can use

```
    String str=null;
    while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
    System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. After running the file I added one more line to see if it still works. It did not and I stumbled upon your answer. It works now. Thank you so much :) @Yash

Comment: Your solution skips one line on every two

Comment: @azro Need one more edition. I just did it. You can check the answer now.

Comment: @Yash why did not you put it at first time ? :p